# How do I specify a grails environment from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails

I'm using Eclipse to develop and run a Grails application.  Inside grails-app/conf/Config.groovy I've created a stanza within the environment for my own tweaks.

Thus:

```
environments {
     dev_leonard {
          <my stuff>
     }
 }
```

When I run from the command line, I can force the use of my environment by specifying the -D as follows:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=dev_leonard run-app
```

But I can't figure out how to do the equivalent from within Eclipse.  I've tried Run->Run Configurations ->  Environment and tried setting environment several different ways, but with no luck.  (I'm not including all the failed experiments here.)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Run As > Run Configurations
```

Find the `run-app` and just change the Grails command.

[image]

Comment: When I follow your suggestion exactly, and don't make typos, it works.  First time I tried it, it failed due to typos.